# Should I avoid ground loops in branch circuits through conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding-and-bonding

I've got some outdoor conduit within which are three separate branch circuits:

1. A general purpose, 20A outdoor receptacle circuit
2. A 15A HVAC circuit
3. A 40A EVSE circuit

I am using NM-B for each circuit on the indoor segment that connects the breaker to the conduit, at which point I transition to THWN. The NM-B has a ground wire included, and I know that I only need to ground the conduit to the 8AWG wire from the EVSE circuit. My question is, **should I not connect the ground wires on the 15A and 20A circuits to avoid creating a ground loop, or does it not matter?**

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry too much about ground loops if you're lined up on runway centerline. Seriously though current does not normally flow through ground so it should be fine.

Comment: "Ground loops" are almost a non-issue in AC building wiring that some folks feel the need to make a big stink out of. If you were wiring a commercial recording studio with tons of sound equipment, maybe. In a home, don't even give it a second thought.

Comment: That was my impression, however, I am fairly used to electronics design (including some PCB fab) where ground loops are sources of endless frustration. That said, the closest equivalent here would actually be neutral loops, not ground loops.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- even for a recording studio, the ground loops themselves are not a problem until you add gear that has [pin 1 wired wrong on its audio connectors](http://pin1problem.com/).  Fix the Pin 1 problems, and the hum will go away, ground loop or no ground loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "ground loop" in question does not matter one bit -- the NEC assumes all involved EGCs are connected together at all junctions, even.  (It's impossible *not* to have them all connected together in a metallic conduit system, for one.)

Note that there are a few exceptions for isolated grounds for certain sensitive equipment, but the benefits of isolated receptacle EGCs are unclear. (Note that the redundant earthing requirement in patient care areas is *not* an isolated equipment grounding requirement!)

Comment: @Kris -- there is sensitive equipment that recommends isolated grounding, but it's not medical equipment -- patient care requirements are for *redundant* EGCs not *isolated* ones

Comment: @ThreePhasEel after i typed the comment I remembered just that!  Thanks !

Comment: @ThreePhasEel A dedicated circuit is basically an isolated ground, no?

Comment: @Kris -- not necessarily, especially in a conduit/metal framing environs